# How to increase the x-axis plot size in seaborn?

Tags: matplotlib, graph, seaborn, data-science, figsize

I am trying to plot a graph using seaborn for different professions and I cannot identify the labels on the x-axis. Here's the image of the graph
[image]

Comment: Try `plt.xticks(rotation=70)` to rotate your labels

Comment: What do you mean by "x-axis plot size"? Please be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

as @Karthik mentioned in the comment, I have tried rotating labels

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Profession", data=df)

ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=40, ha="right")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This worked

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(25,7)
```

- #25 is Width
- #7 is Height

[image]